# RPI CM4 high temperature , 106˚C

Tags: pi-4

I have a board with a raspberry pi CM4 module , everything was fine until now but after connecting/disconnecting to a power source the temperature goes up to 106˚C when booting and the raspberry shuts down.
Nothing is connected to the outputs.
Could you please advise me?

*edit
I have two IO board boards original from Raspberry Pi, I power the board with 12.0V , the output is 5.17V , when I boot the board into power supply the board starts to boot , but the consumption is at 12 volts 900mA , the board boots , heats up to 110°C and shuts down, I have several IO boards and it does it on all of them , so it is probably a faulty CM4 module.

Thank you
[image: temperatures from vcgencmd]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is lacking any details that might lead to an answer.

Comment: `everything was fine until now` so, what happened between the time you bought it and now?

Comment: Everything worked, I moved the board from one room to another and it started doing it , if I knew the details of what happened there I wouldn't have asked for advice. I'm asking if anyone else has had this happen to them.

Comment: I have two IO board boards original from Raspberry Pi, I power the board with 12.0V , the output is 5.17V , when I boot the board into power supply the board starts to boot , but the consumption is at 12 volts 900mA , the board boots , heats up to 110°C and shuts down, I have several IO boards and it does it on all of them , so it is probably a faulty CM4 module.